# Plotly subplot represent same y-axis name with same color and single legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to create a plot for two categories in a subplot. 1st column represent category FF and 2nd column represent category RF in the subplot.

The `x-axis` is always **time** and `y-axis` is remaining columns. In other words, it is a plot with one column vs rest.

1st category and 2nd category always have same column names just only the values differs.

I tried to generate the plot in a `for loop` but the problem is **plotly** treats each column name as distinct and thereby it represents the lines in different color for `y-axis` with same name. As a consequence, in legend also an entry is created.

For example, in first row **Time vs price2010** I want both subplot FF and RF to be represented in same color (say blue) and a single entry in legend.

I tried adding `legendgroup` in `go.Scatter` but it doesn't help.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from plotly import tools
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

CarA = {'Time': [10,20,30,40 ],
        'Price2010': [22000,26000,27000,35000],
        'Price2011': [23000,27000,28000,36000],
        'Price2012': [24000,28000,29000,37000],
        'Price2013': [25000,29000,30000,38000],
        'Price2014': [26000,30000,31000,39000],
        'Price2015': [27000,31000,32000,40000],
        'Price2016': [28000,32000,33000,41000]
        }

ff = DataFrame(CarA)

CarB = {'Time': [8,18,28,38 ],
        'Price2010': [19000,20000,21000,22000],
        'Price2011': [20000,21000,22000,23000],
        'Price2012': [21000,22000,23000,24000],
        'Price2013': [22000,23000,24000,25000],
        'Price2014': [23000,24000,25000,26000],
        'Price2015': [24000,25000,26000,27000],
        'Price2016': [25000,26000,27000,28000]
        }

rf = DataFrame(CarB)

Type = {
'FF' : ff,
'RF' : rf
}

fig = make_subplots(rows=len(ff.columns), cols=len(Type), subplot_titles=('FF','RF'),vertical_spacing=0.3/len(ff.columns))

labels = ff.columns[1:]
for indexC, (cat, values) in enumerate(Type.items()):
    for indexP, params in enumerate(values.columns[1:]):
        trace = go.Scatter(x=values.iloc[:,0], y=values[params], mode='lines', name=params,legendgroup=params)
        fig.append_trace(trace,indexP+1, indexC+1)
        fig.update_xaxes(title_text=values.columns[0],row=indexP+1, col=indexC+1)
        fig.update_yaxes(title_text=params,row=indexP+1, col=indexC+1)
        fig.update_layout(height=2024, width=1024,title_text="Car Analysis")
iplot(fig)
```

[image: output of the code]

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a good solution, but so far I can able to come up only with this hack.

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=len(ff.columns), cols=len(Type), subplot_titles=('FF','RF'),vertical_spacing=0.2/len(ff.columns))

labels = ff.columns[1:]
colors = [ '#a60000', '#f29979', '#d98d36', '#735c00', '#778c23', '#185900', '#00a66f']
legend = True
for indexC, (cat, values) in enumerate(Type.items()):
    for indexP, params in enumerate(values.columns[1:]):
        trace = go.Scatter(x=values.iloc[:,0], y=values[params], mode='lines', name=params,legendgroup=params, showlegend=legend, marker=dict(
            color=colors[indexP]))
        fig.append_trace(trace,indexP+1, indexC+1)
        fig.update_xaxes(title_text=values.columns[0],row=indexP+1, col=indexC+1)
        fig.update_yaxes(title_text=params,row=indexP+1, col=indexC+1)
        fig.update_layout(height=1068, width=1024,title_text="Car Analysis")
    legend = False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you combine your data into a [single tidy data frame](https://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html), you can use a simple [Plotly Express](https://plotly.express/) call to make the chart: `px.line()` with `color`, `facet_row` and `facet_col`